# Android mock gps provider

Tags: android, gps, android-location

My code snippet is:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if(mLocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
    mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

mLocationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            "requiresNetwork" == "", "requiresSatellite" == "",
            "requiresCell" == "", "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
            "supportsAltitude" == "", "supportsSpeed" == "",
            "supportsBearing" == "",

android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
        android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);

// mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
// location);

location.setLatitude(FinalLatitudeIntArray[0]);
location.setLongitude(FinalLongitudeIntArray[0]);
mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, location);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeTestProviderEnabled(ILocationManager.java:1097)
at android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.java:1130)
```

Please help me sorting out this error.
To add.
Earlier the application was running fine, but when I rebooted the system, the application started showing error.

Comment: @rekire Thanks for editing the question. Can you help me out with a suitable solution?

Comment: No problem, so it's simpler to read. Does your device support GPS?

Comment: no, I am providing my own lat and long value.
Yesterday the code was running fine, but today i am getting this error. :( .....

Comment: Could you add some more lines of the stacktrace? The trace seems not be directly related to your code.

Comment: When i remove the removeTestProvider() line, the same exception is thrown for setTestProvider line.. :( .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Android docs on the location manager:

```
removeTestProvider() throws 
IllegalArgumentException    if no provider with the given name exists
```

So, if you're testing on the emulator, the settings for GPS might have been reset by the reboot (**try checking your permissions and DDMS to enable it again**). If on the device, you must have disabled GPS (**go to Settings and enable GPS**).

**EDIT**: Found something relevant: [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857). Basically there's something going on that seems erratic in the emulator. From the comments on that thread, try using `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, like:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true );

    if ( provider == null ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "No location provider found!" );
        return;
    }
```

Go through that thread for further information.

Comment: When i remove the removeTestProvider() line, the same exception is thrown for setTestProvider line.. :( .......

Comment: Then it's almost certain that you have no GPS provider enabled on your device/emulator. It has to have the feature in order to even receive the mock locations.

Comment: I didn't change the emulator setting at all. then why was it working nicely before the reboot???????

Comment: the application is now running smoothly with the code i used before without showing any error.
WHAT WAS THAT???????

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, go through this link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,  as some devices nowadays do not have GPS. A good method is as mentioned by 'varevarao', but i also encountered problem if I use the criteria method. On some devices, it still returns a null at 'getBestProvider' (see code below).

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, false );

    if ( provider == null ) {
        criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true );
        Log.d( "Function", "No location provider found!" );
        return;
    }
```

I did this to solve it (see code below). Not sure whether it is the best method, but it currently works for me. It works by getting the list of 'location providers' available on the device, then grabs the first (should not matter, as i am just using it for mock location).

```
   List<String> tmpProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();

   if (!tmpProviders.isEmpty() && tmpProviders.toArray()[0] != null && !tmpProviders.toArray()[0].toString().isEmpty() ) {
      mocLocationProvider = tmpProviders.toArray()[0].toString();
  } else {// your error goes here }
```