# android location manager issue with gps

Tags: java, android, gps, location, locationmanager

I am trying to set a mock location to a Scotland for example. What am I doing wrong? I've declared my location manager in the oncreate().How can I mock and set the coordinates for my entire phone?

Error:

```
04-21 14:08:23.835  21449-21449/com.example.ankhit.saveme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:956)
            at android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1194)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.setMockLocation(UserLocation.java:208)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.access$000(UserLocation.java:41)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation$4.onClick(UserLocation.java:168)
```

My Method:

```
private void setMockLocation() {
          mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          mLocationManager.addTestProvider
                    (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    "requiresNetwork" == "",
                    "requiresSatellite" == "",
                    "requiresCell" == "",
                    "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                    "supportsAltitude" == "",
                    "supportsSpeed" == "",
                    "supportsBearing" == "",

                    android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                    android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
                    );

            Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            newLocation.setLatitude (51.4276462);
            newLocation.setLongitude(-0.5509257);

            newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            true
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                            null,
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            newLocation
                    );
```

}

Comment: Have you declared permissions for accessing mock location in your manifest???

Comment: @Vikalp, yes both in my normal and debug manifests...not really sure what the issue is?

Comment: try to use getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) and see of the GPS provider exist

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549701/android-mock-gps-provider

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, I came across that page, but don't fully understand it, could I get an explanation?