# Location Error with GPS?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, gps, location

I've got my location class with my location manager. I've got my method for setting up a mock location however keep getting the error 'GPS Provider Unknown' even though all my permissions are set?

Am I missing a location listener linked with the method of the mock location? My method is influenced from other tutorials however, not to sure why the 'GPS Provider Unknown' is happening? How do I mock the location of my phone using the set coordinates and not get the error?

**Class:**

```
public class UserLocation extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    /**
     * Everything For Database: Connection Links, References, and Method Invocations
     * */

    //JSON Parser
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //String id
    String id;

    //For Updating the Database with Locations
    private static String url_add_profile = "http://IP:8888/android_connect/add_location.php";

    //For Updating the Database with Locations
    private static String url_get_location = "http://IP:8888/android_connect/get_location.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    //LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = UserLocation.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Everything for Location Requests
     * */

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000; //1 second

    private Location mLastLocation;

    //Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    //Boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    //Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 seconds
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 seconds
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    /**
     * Fields
     * */
    //Variables declared
    private TextView lblLocation, lblLocation2, lblLocation3, lblDummyLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates, btnAddLocation, btnViewPhoneLocation, btnViewAllPhoneLocation, btnSetPhoneLocation, btnStartLocationService, btnStopLocationService;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_location);

        //Variables initialised and linked to corresponding id's.
        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        lblLocation2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation2);
        lblLocation3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation3);
        lblDummyLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDummyLocation);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);
        btnAddLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddLocation);
        btnViewPhoneLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewPhoneLocation);
        btnViewAllPhoneLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewAllPhoneLocation);
        btnSetPhoneLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetPhoneLocation);
        btnStartLocationService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartLocationService);
        btnStopLocationService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopLocationService);

        //First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            //Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            //Method for Location Request
            createLocationRequest();
        }
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);//Getting system services

        //Getting location details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //Getting location id (pid) from intent
        id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        /**
         * Button Clicks: They call a method or redirect to another activity
         * */
        //Add location button click listener
        btnAddLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AddLocation().execute();
            }
        });//Executes Async Task to add a location to the database

        //Get location button click listener
        btnViewPhoneLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new GetLocationDetails().execute();
            }
        });//Executes Async Task to get the location from the database

        //Get all location button click listener
        btnViewAllPhoneLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserLocation.this, ViewAllLocations.class));
            }
        });//Starts an Intent to go to another activity to view all the locations stored in the database

        //Set location button click listener
        btnSetPhoneLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setMockLocation();
            }
        });//Executes the method to set the phone's location

        // Show location button click listener
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayLocation();
            }
        });//Executes the method to display the location

        // Toggling the periodic location updates
        btnStartLocationUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
            }
        });//Executes to location updates

        //Start location service
        btnStartLocationService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyServices.class));
            }
        });//Starts an Intent to go to another activity to start the background service

        //Stop location service
        btnStopLocationService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyServices.class));
            }
        });//Starts an Intent to go to another activity to stop the background service


    }
        //Initiates the method to set the phones location
        private void setMockLocation() {
          mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          mLocationManager.addTestProvider
                    (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    "requiresNetwork" == "",
                    "requiresSatellite" == "",
                    "requiresCell" == "",
                    "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                    "supportsAltitude" == "",
                    "supportsSpeed" == "",
                    "supportsBearing" == "",

                    android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                    android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
                    );

            Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            newLocation.setLatitude (32.4276462);
            newLocation.setLongitude(23.5509257);

            newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            true
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                            null,
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            newLocation
                    );
        }

    /**
     * Methods that initialise GoogleApi Client
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();

        // Resuming the periodic location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     * */
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
            lblLocation2.setText("" + latitude);
            lblLocation3.setText("" + longitude);


        } else {

            lblLocation
                    .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     * */
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     * */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        //Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
5-09 16:28:45.577    9070-9070/com.example.ankhit.saveme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:956)
            at android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1194)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.setMockLocation(UserLocation.java:215)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.access$000(UserLocation.java:41)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation$4.onClick(UserLocation.java:173)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
```

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13549844/3168859) help you ?

Comment: @Lal, Not really, throws the rest of my class into errors? Any idea in relation to my code?