# Mock Location FATAL ERROR void android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, gps, location

For a client of mine, I am trying to test his restaurant finder app (Which will find restaurants close to your location). But since this requires a lot of mock locations I implemented an activity with a map where I could quickly select a location and mock that area's context. The issue I am having is that upon executing the function setMockLocation(locationMock) I get a FATAL EXCEPTION with no idea how to solve this.

Currently, I have this class to handle the setting of the Mock location.

```
package HIDDEN;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class locationHandler {

     public static LocationManager mLocationManager;

    public static void setMockLocation(LatLng location) {
        mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        mLocationManager.addTestProvider
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        "requiresNetwork" == "",
                        "requiresSatellite" == "",
                        "requiresCell" == "",
                        "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                        "supportsAltitude" == "",
                        "supportsSpeed" == "",
                        "supportsBearing" == "",

                        android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                        android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
                );

        Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



        newLocation.setLatitude (location.latitude);
        newLocation.setLongitude(location.longitude);

        newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        true
                );

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                        null,
                        System.currentTimeMillis()
                );

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        newLocation
                );
    }
}
```

I also have set this in the debugging AndroidManifest.xml as it would not allow me to set it in the main manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

To call the setMockLocation function I use the following code which I am passing through a LatLang of the desired location I would like to mock to.

```
locationHandler.setMockLocation(locationMock);
```

Upon executing this on my phone for debugging and clicking the button to mock the location I get the following error.

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: HIDDEN, PID: 10688
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at HIDDEN.locationHandler.setMockLocation(locationHandler.java:17)
        at HIDDEN.MapsActivity$5.onClick(MapsActivity.java:220)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:134)
```

Thankyou for anyone who takes time to look at this for me.

Comment: Your `stacktrace` tells you exactly where the error is. Your `mLocationManager` is `null`

Comment: what should I set it with?

Comment: `LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` Have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: After doing what @Pztar suggested i now have a new FATAL ERROR
Provider "gps" unknown
any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13549844/1269953